# How to handle EditText by Seekbar in Android

Tags: android, seekbar

Hi all i have an EditText an a seekbar .I want to develop such app like that when we scroll seekbar then value in EditText should be increment or Decrement.So if any know please help me in regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a listener on the SeekBar and use that to update the EditText.

Comment: which listener and how can you tell me in deep

Comment: @Sajan why don't you look at SeekBar in the Android documentation. It's all there for you.